# Multiplayer Keyboarding In Pygame Python 2.7 issues

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

We are having some issues with our game that we are making. The problem is that player 1 and player 2 are just jumping not going left or right like we had programmed them to do. Could someone please look over our code and see where we went wrong?

Thank You 
Chuglydude

Main Game Code:

```
#The Battle of...

import pygame, sys, random
from livewires import games, color
from classes import *
from process import *
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

SCREENWIDTH = 800
SCREENHEIGHT = 640
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT), 0, 32)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 24

background = pygame.image.load("background1.png")

bug_list = ["Bob.jpg", "Sophia.png", "Raxster.png", "Tortle.png"]
width_list = [193, 60, 218, 60]
height_list = [277, 94, 246, 100]
x = random.randrange(0, len(bug_list), 1)
y = random.randrange(0, len(bug_list), 1)

Player1 = Bug(0,
              SCREENHEIGHT - height_list[x],
              SCREENWIDTH,
              SCREENHEIGHT,
              bug_list[x])
Player2 = Bug(SCREENWIDTH - width_list[y],
              SCREENHEIGHT - height_list[y],
              SCREENWIDTH,
              SCREENHEIGHT,
              bug_list[y])

def game():
    while True:
        Player1.motion(SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT)
        process1(Player1)
        Player2.motion(SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT)
        process2(Player2)
        BaseClass.allsprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        screen.blit(background, (0,0))
        clock.tick(FPS)


def main():
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        pygame.display.set_caption('Game Menu')

        menu_items = ('Start', 'Quit')
        funcs = {'Start': game,
                 'Quit': sys.exit}

        gm = GameMenu(screen, funcs.keys(), funcs)
        gm.run()




main()
```

Classes Code:

```
import pygame, random, sys

pygame.init()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0 , 0)

class MenuItem(pygame.font.Font):
    def __init__(self, text, font=None, font_size=30,
                 font_color=(WHITE), (pos_x, pos_y)=(0, 0)):
        pygame.font.Font.__init__(self, font, font_size)
        self.text = text
        self.font_size = font_size
        self.font_color = font_color
        self.label = self.render(self.text, 1, self.font_color)
        self.width = self.label.get_rect().width
        self.height = self.label.get_rect().height
        self.dimensions = (self.width, self.height)
        self.pos_x = pos_x
        self.pos_y = pos_y
        self.position = pos_x, pos_y
        self.is_selected = False

    def is_mouse_selection(self, (posx, posy)):
        if (posx >= self.pos_x and posx <= self.pos_x + self.width) and \
        (posy >= self.pos_y and posy <= self.pos_y + self.height):
            return True
        return False

    def set_position(self, x, y):
        self.position = (x, y)
        self.pos_x = x
        self.pos_y = y

    def set_font_color(self, rgb_tuple):
        self.font_color = rgb_tuple
        self.label = self.render(self.text, 1, self.font_color)


class GameMenu():
    def __init__(self,
                 screen,
                 items,
                 funcs,
                 bg_color = BLACK,
                 font = None,
                 font_size = 30,
                 font_color = WHITE):
        self.screen = screen
        self.scr_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        self.scr_height = self.screen.get_rect().height

        self.bg_color = bg_color
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.funcs = funcs
        self.items = []
        for index, item in enumerate(items):
            menu_item = MenuItem(item, font, font_size, font_color)

            # t_h: total height of text block
            t_h = len(items) * menu_item.height

            pos_x = (self.scr_width / 2) - (menu_item.width / 2)
            pos_y = (self.scr_height / 2) - (t_h / 2) + \
                    ((index * 2) + index * menu_item.height)

            menu_item.set_position(pos_x, pos_y)
            self.items.append(menu_item)

        self.mouse_is_visible = True
        self.cur_item = None

    def set_mouse_visibility(self):
        if self.mouse_is_visible:
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
        else:
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    def set_item_selection(self, key):
        """Marks the MenuItem chosen via up and down keys."""
        for item in self.items:
            #Return all to neutral
            item.set_italic(False)
            item.set_font_color(WHITE)

        if self.cur_item is None:
            self.cur_item = 0
        else:
            #Find the chosen item
            if key == pygame.K_UP and self.cur_item > 0:
                self.cur_item -= 1
            elif key == pygame.K_UP and self.cur_item == 0:
                self.cur_item = len(self.items) - 1
            elif key == pygame.K_DOWN and \
                 self.cur_item < len(self.items) - 1:
                self.cur_item += 1
            elif key == pygame.K_DOWN and \
                 self.cur_item == len(self.items) - 1:
                self.cur_item = 0

        self.items[self.cur_item].set_italic(True)
        self.items[self.cur_item].set_font_color(RED)

        #Finally check if Enter or Space is pressed
        if key == pygame.K_SPACE or key == pygame.K_RETURN:
            text = self.items[self.cur_item].text
            selfs.funcs[text]()

    def set_mouse_selection(self, item, mpos):
        """Marks the MenuItem the mouse cursor hovers on."""
        if item.is_mouse_selection(mpos):
            item.set_font_color(RED)
            item.set_italic(True)
        else:
            item.set_font_color(WHITE)
            item.set_italic(False)

    def run(self):
        mainloop = True
        while mainloop:
            #Limit frame speed to 50 FPS
            self.clock.tick(50)

            mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    mainloop = False
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    self.mouse_is_visible = False
                    self.set_item_selection(event.key)                
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    for item in self.items:
                        if item.is_mouse_selection(mpos):
                            self.funcs[item.text]()

            if pygame.mouse.get_rel() != (0, 0):
                self.mouse_is_visible = True
                self.cur_item = None

            #Is the mouse visible?
            self.set_mouse_visibility()

            #Redraw the background
            self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)

            for item in self.items:
                if self.mouse_is_visible:
                    self.set_mouse_selection(item, mpos)
                self.screen.blit(item.label, item.position)

            pygame.display.flip()


class BaseClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        BaseClass.allsprites.add(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_string)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

class Bug(BaseClass):

    List = pygame.sprite.Group()
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string):

        BaseClass.__init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string)
        self.velx, self.vely = 0, 5
        self.jumping, self.go_down = False, False 

    def motion(self, SCREENWIDTH,SCREENHEIGHT):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        predicted_location = self.rect.x + self.velx

        if predicted_location < 0:
            self.velx = 0
        elif predicted_location + self.width > SCREENWIDTH:
            self.velx = 0

        self.rect.x += self.velx

        self.__jump(SCREENHEIGHT)


    def __jump(self, SCREENHEIGHT):

        max_jump = 75

        if self.jumping:
            if self.rect.y < max_jump:
               self.go_down = True
            if self.go_down:
                self.rect.y += self.vely
                predicted_location = self.rect.y + self.vely
                if predicted_location + self.height > SCREENHEIGHT:
                    self.jumping = False
                    self.go_down = False
                if predicted_location + self.height < 0:
                    self.jumping = False
                    self.go_down = False
            else:
                self.rect.y -= self.vely
```

Processes Code:

```
import pygame, sys

def process1(bug):
    #PROCESSING

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            bug.velx = 5
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            bug.velx = -5
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            bug.jumping = True
        #attacks
        if keys[pygame.K_1]:
            bug.velx = 50
        if keys[pygame.K_2]:
            bug.velx = -50
        else:
            bug.velx = 0

def process2(bug):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            bug.velx = 5
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            bug.velx = -5
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            bug.jumping = True
        #attacks
        if keys[pygame.K_1]:
            bug.velx = 50
        if keys[pygame.K_2]:
            bug.velx = -50
        else:
            bug.velx = 0
```

Comment: "Why is my code not working?" questions are only acceptable if you provide a clear problem statement and the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. Don't just paste your whole code, nobody will read it.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for letting us know! Unfortunately, we have no idea where the problem is as we've gone over it several times. So we had no idea which 'minimum amount of code' to post, as it could be anywhere, as far as we know.

Comment: Then this is a splendid opportunity to learn some debugging. Include print statements and try to find the point in your code where things start to go wrong. Throw out everything that is not related to the error.

Comment: @timgeb please be nice an help me please because I am allowed this is the content in our code.

Comment: if player is jumping all the time then probably you forgot `bug.jumping = False` in some place(s). Use `print()` to trace variables and find correct place for `bug.jumping = False`

Comment: Hi furas, thank you! Our player isn't jumping all the time. It only jumps when we press the corresponding key. However, jumping is the only thing it seems to do. Our problem is that when we press the left and right keys, our characters won't move at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if keys[pygame.K_2]:
        bug.velx = -50
    else:
        bug.velx = 0
```

Unless you are holding down K_2, velx will always be 0.

Comment: Dear user 3757614 we want to know so number 1 and 2 are the characters attack but we need help moving left and right it's not working. But thank you for the suggestion on about the 1 and 2 button that helps.

Comment: The a, d, 1, and 2 buttons all control the same variable: velx. If you are holding down a, velx will be set to -5, then reset to 0 in the else clause.

Comment: Thank you user3757614 here is something else We want the character to move only if we hold down the #2 key, otherwise he will be in constant motion. Not sure that’s what we’re looking for.

Comment: If you want the character to move only when 2 is held down, then replace that section with "if not keys[pygame.K_2]: bug.velx = 0"

Comment: Ok thank you user3757614 but ok we have 2 and 1 those are attacks moves we need to set the process left and right key to work